# When making a function can I prompt arguments till a criteria is met?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a plot that take plot wise functions and connects the lines. It will be however many lines. I want to prompt arguments until the input is a "no".
Example:

```
R:"Enter slope, intercept"
User:*input*
R:"Enter slope, intercept"
User:*input*
R:"Enter slope, intercept"
User:"no"
R:"Thank you for inputs"
```

then a graph appears

Comment: I think you want `readline` within a `while` loop?

Answer (score 0):

```r
myfunc <- function() {
  slopes <- intercepts <- numeric(0)
  while (TRUE) {
    user <- tolower(readline("Enter 'slope,intercept': "))
    if (trimws(user) == "no") {
      break
    }
    if (!nzchar(user)) {
      warning("Don't get short with me, I asked you a question ... or type 'no' to exit", call. = FALSE)
      next
    }
    parsed <- tryCatch(
      unlist(lapply(strsplit(user, ",")[[1]], as.numeric)),
      warning = function(w) w, error = function(e) e)
    if (inherits(parsed, c("error","warning"))) {
      warning("That made no sense to me ('", conditionMessage(parsed),
              "'), please try again", call. = FALSE)
      next
    }
    if (length(parsed) != 2L) {
      warning("I did not see (exactly) two values there, please try again", call. = FALSE)
      next
    }
    if (anyNA(parsed) || !is.numeric(parsed)) {
      warning("I see two things but at least one is non-numeric, please try again", call. = FALSE)
      next
    }
    slopes <- c(slopes, parsed[[1]])
    intercepts <- c(intercepts, parsed[[2]])
    lims <- range(c(0, intercepts))
    plot(NA, type = "n", xlim = lims, ylim = lims)
    ign <- mapply(abline, intercepts, slopes)
  }
  message("Thank you for your inputs, have a nice day")
}
```

Execution:

```r
myfunc()
# Enter 'slope,intercept': 
2,3
# Enter 'slope,intercept': 
3,2
# Enter 'slope,intercept': 
2.3
# Warning: I did not see (exactly) two values there, please try again
# Enter 'slope,intercept': 
2,abc
# Warning: That made no sense to me ('NAs introduced by coercion'), please try again
# Enter 'slope,intercept': 
2,3,4
# Warning: I did not see (exactly) two values there, please try again
# Enter 'slope,intercept': 
no
# Thank you for your inputs, have a nice day
```

You need to consider how you want to set x/y limits, this is currently naive and likely insufficient.

Comment: Thanks, chief. This was helpful. Can you explain slopes <- intercepts <- numeric(0) for me?

Comment: Chained assignment. Same thing as `slopes <- numeric(0) ; intercepts <- numeric(0)`.